# Get Thing Shadow of Aws iot thing in lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I was trying to get the thing shadow of a resource of aws iot in lambda function but the given code is giving null value on success instead of a data. Please let me know where is the problem and what changes should i do to make it work fine. Thanks in advance.

```
var AWS=require('aws-sdk');
var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({endpoint: 'XXXXXXXXX.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'});
var params = {
thingName: 'thing_name' /* required */
};

exports.handler=function(event,context){
payload1=new Buffer(event.payload);
console.log(payload1); 
iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response

  context.succeed(data);

});

};
```

Comment: if you run `aws iot list-things` from the CLI what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

There are few places which need to be changed. Here is the new code:

```
getIotShadow: function (thingName) {
    config.IOT_BROKER_ENDPOINT = "xxxxxxxxx.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; // also called the REST API endpoint
    config.IOT_BROKER_REGION = "us-east-1"; // eu-west-1 corresponds to the Ireland Region.  Use us-east-1 for the N. Virginia region
    config.IOT_THING_NAME = thingName;
    AWS.config.region = config.IOT_BROKER_REGION;
    var iotData = new AWS.IotData({
        endpoint: config.IOT_BROKER_ENDPOINT
    });

    var paramsGet = {
        "thingName": config.IOT_THING_NAME /* required */
    };

    iotData.getThingShadow(paramsGet, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error : " + err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```